# ANDROID:add the custom view to a grid view

Tags: android

in my android, I have list and Each list items will display three GridViews. One GridView displays all items with their details, And second will display some operation regarding to that list and then third will show the logout operation.

Is it possible to implement? If yes please provide me the best way to implement ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a grid in a ListView , You can prefer GridLayout instead of grid view.
Customize your listview item by following xml code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/whole_row"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
>    </GridLayout>
 <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
>    </GridLayout>
 <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
>    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```